# Cloudant returns 500 function_clause error on document update but actually succeeds

Tags: java, couchdb, cloudant, ibm-cloud

I have a Java/Liberty application running in Bluemix which uses a Cloudant database as a Bluemix service.

The application makes updates to documents in Cloudant. During the night one of these updates failed with a 500 "function_clause" error. Unfortunately we don't log the exact data that was submitted, but in this case I don't think it matters because the request appears to have actually succeeded (which implies there was nothing actually wrong with the data submitted). Our log shows a successful update of the same document a few minutes before:

```
[4/23/15 6:02:47:790 UTC] 00011bf6 CloudantDBCon I   Storing object: <mydoc> revision: 28786-84dc6b5f33dc3c54041bd430ecfd3db7
[4/23/15 6:02:47:844 UTC] 00011bf6 CloudantDBCon I   RESTResponse:201:{"ok":true,"id":"<mydoc>","rev":"28787-f932d7d249fd6d36d8b0e692f6e77abd"}
```

Note that the next revision should be 28787. Then the error occurs less than a minute later. There are no other attempts to update this document in between, so it is not a conflict:

```
[4/23/15 6:03:03:215 UTC] 00011cc9 CloudantDBCon I   Storing object: <mydoc> revision: 28787-f932d7d249fd6d36d8b0e692f6e77abd
[4/23/15 6:03:10:171 UTC] 00011cc9 CloudantDBCon I   RESTResponse:500:{"error":"function_clause","reason":null,"ref":1199554705}
```

However, a couple minutes after that there is another successful update:

```
[4/23/15 6:05:39:605 UTC] 00011b5e CloudantDBCon I   Storing object: <mydoc> revision: 28788-306b2753e972f9d664d22cfadd9b0f3d
[4/23/15 6:05:40:368 UTC] 00011b5e CloudantDBCon I   RESTResponse:201:{"ok":true,"id":"<mydoc>","rev":"28789-0325241da136f39780ff4b2f97438182"}
```

Note that this successful update was revision 28788, implying that the 28787 update which received the error was actually performed. And indeed, I know from other information in the log what the 28787 revision was attempting to accomplish, and when I examine the database manually, I can tell that the change made in 28787 was in fact made in the database. So the error appears to be incorrect.

This is a problem because our application returned an error to our user as a result of this indicating that the update was not made, when in fact it was.

So my questions specifically are a) what does this error mean (I can't find anything explaining it anywhere) and b) is there something we could have done wrong to cause this, or is it just a bug?

I suppose we could GET the document back again after seeing the 500 error and verify that the data was actually written, but that's a pretty ugly solution.

Edit:

I can't post all the code that's relevant to this, but the immediate portion that generated the trace statements quoted in the question is this:

```
public void storeObject(String id, JSONObject obj) {
    try {
        String rev = null;
        try {
            rev = obj.getString("_rev");
        } catch (JSONException jse) {
            rev = "none";
        }
        log.info("Storing object: " + id + " revision: " + rev);
        RESTResponse response = RESTClient.RESTRequestWithRetry(REQUEST_METHOD_PUT,
                                                                URL + "/" + id,
                                                                obj.toString(),
                                                                username,
                                                                password,
                                                                RETRY_INTERVAL);
        log.info("storeObject: " + response.toString());
        ...
```

You can see from this at least how it matches up with the trace statements, that the revision in the object was correct.

The basic question is why did Cloudant perform the update yet claim that it didn't by returning 500?

Comment: You should always make sure you have the latest revision when updating a doc.

Comment: It does have the latest revision. If you look at the response from the first (successful) update cited above, the second (failing) update uses the correct next revision. There were no updates in between. And as I mentioned in the question, the update is actually being made in the database, so it appears that the error return was wrong.

Comment: Can you share some of your code?  Hard to debug this without a little code.

Comment: As noted in [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285773/couchdb-error-on-specific-document-function-clause-error-in-http-request), a 'function_clause' error might indicate a problem with JavaScript.  Take a look at the map/reduce functions to look for errors.  Is it possible that concurrent updates from multiple instances of the app are colliding in Cloudant and one succeeds, but the other fails?

Comment: @jimmc, thanks, I had seen that post but I don't think it applies here. Because the problem occurs very rarely, and because the call actually succeeded even though it reported failure, it seems unlikely to be a problem with our code. It has been recommended to me that I open a ticket with Cloudant support, which I will do. I'll post here again if I get any resolution from them.

Comment: hello @MarcFraioli have you solved your issue with Cloudant?